# How to use a shiro native session in a grails web application?

Tags: grails, shiro, session-management

Currently, I am using the default HttpSession object in both controllers and gsp pages:

In controllers:

```
...
session.mykey = anObject;  // adding an object to session
...
if (session.otherkey) {    // performing some checking
```

In GSPs:

```
...
<g:if test="${session.mykey}">
...
```

I'd like to have a "remember me" functionality. Shiro has already it built in. However, as far as I understood, in order to do it I have to use the shiro native session mode (in Config.groovy: security.shiro.session.mode="native"). By default, it persists the session state, so objects will remain in the session as far as the cookie expires or the user logs off.

Is my understanding right?

Then i will have to change my controllers to this:

```
def shiroSession = SecurityUtils.subject.session
shiroSession.setAttribute("mykey",anObject)
....
if (shiroSession.getAttribute("otherkey") ){
```

And my views to this:

```
<g:if test="${SecurityUtils.subject.session.getAttribute('mykey')}">
```

So, my questions are:

- Is that right?
- Can't I just use the previous way to access the session?
- Do I have to turn off the default http session in some configuration?

Comment: you don't need the native session to use "remember me".

Comment: what do you suggest? Can you point me some links? I tried the native session after reading this post: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Forcing-authentication-of-user-in-Grails-filter-using-Shiro-tp3698679p3702316.html

Comment: From: https://grails.org/plugin/shiro  look at access control by convention.  You just set the ```accessControl(auth:false)  ``` in ```SecurityUtils.groovy```.  Should work if you are passing the rememberMe flag in properly.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up keeping objects in the session persistently (until cookie expires). Here is what i did:

In the login method in the controller:

```
if (! session.currentProfile){
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject()
if (currentUser.isRemembered()){
    boolean success = configureSession(session, currentUser.getPrincipal())
        if (success){
        ... 
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

The first "if" checks whether the session has the object i need.

The configureSession method puts in the session all information I need.